# How to improve WP-Rest atrocious response time?

Tags: javascript, rest-api

I'm going to be very straight forward here.

I have a headless WP install and made my front-end in Vue.JS

Since I've started this project, the load times for the API requests were high but I think we just reached the slowest possible situation and I really do not know how to tackle this.
I'm getting up to, sometimes more, 50 seconds of response time loading only 10 posts. I have a few custom post types that also take forever to load.

I've tried caching with a few plugins, tried to disable all unnecessary plugins as well, both with no sucess.

All these requests are made using Axios.get(), I also tried to change to fetch() but had the same results.

The site can be found here: https://academiadoautismo.com.br/

[image: wp-rest response times]

Thanks in advance for any ideas!

Comment: Try using object and database cache with something like redis or memcached. Check your queries to make sure they're leveraging caching and your queries aren't overly complicated.

Comment: The thing is, the overall WP performance is fine. The admin is running smooth. The only problem are the Axios calls to the API. Also, if I try to access the API endpoint directly, it also takes a lot of time to load, this may indicate that the problem is not in my Axios calls. I'm on a Plesk server so, no redis or memcached.

Comment: Try to profile it in more detail, to find the bottleneck. Many tools out there to help with that. One of the quick tests is to disable all plugins and use the default theme and go from there. Remember to backup before testing.

Comment: I've already tried that. Disabled everything but the essential (ACF to REST), tried with 2 of the default themes. No changes. This site is very simple its basically a blog with a few custom post types that are very simple themselves. Theres just 3 plugins other than ACF to REST.

Comment: Try with a clean vanilla install just to see the baseline. Profiling is the key to avoid guesswork.